# How could I save hitbox information in Java?

Tags: java

Currently I've been using properties files, and then reading them to assign values to my Hitbox class.

For example in the properties file:

```
hitboxPosX=50

in code:
int hitboxPosX = Integer.ParseInt(Properties.getProperty("hitboxPosX");
```

While it works, it feels really clunky and to make a "default" value, I'd have to copy the file for each move. Is there a way where I could define each individual hitbox's properties inside Java itself rather than working with text files?

This question may be hard to decipher, but hopefully I've at least somewhat communicated what my problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a service which can optionally take the default value or the value read from the properties file instead.  Effectively:  wrap the extracting of data, and allow yourself the flexibility to get whatever values you care about at any instant in time.

As an example:

```
// Assume an enum PropertyType exists, and
// assume a constant HITBOX_DEFAULT_VALUE exists as well
public int getHitboxOrDefault(PropertyType useDefault) {
    if(useDefault == PropertyType.USE_DEFAULT_VALUE) {
        return HITBOX_DEFAULT_VALUE;
    } else {
        return Integer.parseInt(Properties.getProperty("hitboxPosX"));
    }
}
```

Comment: So would the best way to implement hitboxes be to make files for each character state and then read from them? That's what I've been doing and I can't help but feel it's suboptimal.

Comment: If each character is *different* and has *different* values for hitboxes, then that's kind of the world you've inherited.  If they're not, then surely you can leverage some kind of base class to apply a base amount of HP, then the extensions only add (or subtract) deltas from that.  That's out of scope for *this* question you're asking, though.

Comment: I'm new to the service, so I'm not exactly sure how to phrase my questions in order to get the best responses, but I'm trying to code a fighting game, and each character is different. In addition to this, each character has different states, and each state has an associated hitbox, hurtbox and animation. 

I have a folder for each character, and in each folder is a list of folders --each representing a different "state." There are properties files for all three of these pieces of information (hitbox,hurtbox and animation). 

Is that how you would go about managing this?